# how to select distinct row in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

`total_site` model has `project_id`, `user_id` and `total_site_id` column. i am able to access `site` that belongs to current_user signed in. now i want to access `project_id` distinct column but i am getting repeations of same project_id. how can i resolve this problem in rails
. here is my code-

projects_controller.rb

```
 def new

    @projects = TotalSite.where(user_id: current_user.id) #here is want distinct project_id column

    @sites = TotalSite.where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

form.html.erb

```
        <div class="field medium-4 columns">
          <%= form.label :select_project,:class=>"required" %>
          <%= form.collection_select :project_id, @projects, :id, :project_id, prompt: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="field medium-4 columns">
          <%= form.label :select_site,:class=>"required" %>
          <%= form.collection_select :site_id, @sites, :id, :name, prompt: true %>

        </div>
```

Comment: You want to end up with sites list or projects list in @projects? 
project_id is related to an associated Project model? if so, please share the association definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a model `Project` which `has_many :total_sites` from your description of:

> `total_site` model has `project_id`

If you want your `@projects` to be all unique project id-s for the current user, then

```
@projects = TotalSite.where(user_id: current_user.id).distinct.pluck(:project_id)
```

If you want it to be the actual `Project` records, then

```
Project.joins(:total_sites).where(total_sites: { user_id: current_user.id }).distinct
```